# Highlight Listbox Function

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Im looking for assistance in my code in regards to my listbox highlighting and actively changing the highlighted choice based off active sheet.

my listbox auto populates based off the sheets within the workbook and can change active worksheet based off selection but does not auto highlight the initial loaded active sheet as the selection and when manually selected on the workbook does not reflect the changes.

```
Public ActiveSheetChoice As String

    Private Sub ActiveSheetDisplay_AfterUpdate()

        ActiveSheetChoice = ActiveSheetDisplay.Text

    ' Change sheet based on choice
        Worksheets(ActiveSheetChoice).Activate

    End Sub
Private Sub ActiveSheetDisplayRefresh_Click()

' Declaration
    Dim N As Long

' Clear exsisting entries
    ActiveSheetDisplay.Clear

' Function
    For N = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ActiveSheetDisplay.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name
    Next N

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ' Declaration
        Dim N As Long


    ' Initalization of active sheet display
        For N = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
            ActiveSheetDisplay.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name
        Next N

End Sub

Private Sub ImportButton_Click()

' Declare Variables
    Dim TargetBook As Workbook
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook

' Set Active Workbook
    Set SourceBook = ThisWorkbook

' Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
    'The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

        ' Makes sure the user can select only one file
            .AllowMultiSelect = False

        ' Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
            .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1

        ' Show the dialog box
            .Show

        ' Opening selected file
            For Each Book In .SelectedItems
                Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Open(Book)
                CopyAllSheets SourceBook, TargetBook
                TargetBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Next Book

        ' Refresh Active Sheets
            Call ActiveSheetDisplayRefresh_Click

        ' Inform User of completion
            MsgBox "Data import complete"

        End With

End Sub

' Copy Sheet Function
    Sub CopyAllSheets(Source As Workbook, Target As Workbook)

    ' Determine Number of sheets to copy
        totalSheets = Target.Sheets.Count

    ' Copy
        For Each sh In Target.Sheets
          sh.Copy after:=Source.Sheets(Source.Sheets.Count)
        Next sh

    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveOptionButton_Click()

        ' Save workbook Function
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            MsgBox "Workbook saved!"

    End Sub


' Using Query Close event of Userform
    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

' Display information message dialog box
        If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then

            'Changing Cancel variable value to True
                Cancel = True
                MsgBox "Main Options cannot be closed"

        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListBox won't show any highlight because no selection has been made. When no selection was made the ListBox has no `Value` (`Text`). If you assign a `Value` programmatically it will be highlighted automatically. If you assign a value not in the list an error will occur.

Consider using the Worksheet_Activate event to set a value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheetDisplay.Text = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

The *On Error* statement has the function of preventing a crash if the ActiveSheet isn't in the list for whatever reason.

The above idea has been implemented in the solution presented below. You will need to adapt parts of it to use the variable names you are already familiar with.

1. You should have a userform. I have named mine *MyForm*. Replace the name in my code with one you like better wherever it appears.
2. My *MyForm* has a ListBox called `ListBox1`. Replace the name in my code with one you like better wherever it appears.
3. Install the following 3 procedures in a standard code module.

   Sub ShowMyForm()
       ' Variatus @STO 21 Feb 2020

   ```
   Dim UForm As MyForm

   If FormIndex = True Then             ' prevents creation of several instances
       Debug.Print "New form"
       Set UForm = New MyForm
       UForm.Show vbModeless
   End If
   ```

   End Sub

   Sub RefreshMyForm()
       ' Variatus @STO 21 Feb 2020

   ```
   Dim i As Integer

   i = FormIndex
   If i > -1 Then
       UserForms(i).ListBox1.Text = ActiveSheet.Name
   End If
   ```

   End Sub

   Private Function FormIndex() As Integer
       ' Variatus @STO 21 Feb 2020

   ```
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = UserForms.Count To 1 Step -1
       If UserForms(i - 1).Name = "MyForm" Then Exit For
   Next i

   FormIndex = i - 1
   ```

   End Function
4. This procedure goes into the `ThisWorkbook` code module.

   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       ' Variatus @STO 21 Feb 2020
       ShowMyForm
   End Sub
5. The procedure below goes into the userform's code module. You can adjust the way the list box is filled to exclude some sheets but it's important that you set the `V` variable to indicate the currently active sheet.

   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
       ' Variatus @STO 21 Feb 2020

   ```
   Dim Ws As Worksheet
   Dim Arr() As String
   Dim V As Integer
   Dim i As Integer

   With Worksheets
       ReDim Arr(1 To .Count)
       For i = 1 To .Count
           Arr(i) = .Item(i).Name
           If .Item(i) Is ActiveSheet Then V = i
       Next i
   End With

   With ListBox1
       .List = Arr
       .ListIndex = V - 1
   End With
   ```

   End Sub
6. Finally, this is the procedure you need to install in the code sheet of every worksheet listed in the listbox.

   Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
       ' Variatus @STO 21 Feb 2020

   ```
   RefreshMyForm
   ```

   End Sub

Now, to put it all together: When the workbook is opened the procedure `ShowMyForm` is called. If the form gets deleted accidentally thereafter you can reinstate it by calling the same procedure or the `Workbook_Open` event procedure (which can also be called with F5). If `ShowMyForm` is called repeatedly it will refuse to open more than one instance of the form.

When the form is shown its Initialize event procedure runs. This procedure lists the sheets in the listbox and sets the current ActiveSheet.

When you change sheets a new sheet gets activated and the Worksheet_Activate event occurs. The relative event procedure calls the ListBox's Initialize event, resetting the list.

When you select another sheet from the listbox it gets activate by this procedure in the UserForm's code sheet. However, I think you have this already.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    ' Variatus @STO 21 Feb 2020
    Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I should have posted more code but i have the ability to make an active selection, i was more referring to when the workbook initially loads have it make the active sheet selected. Also somehow get it to reflect changes that are made manually with the mouse on the workbook instead of in the listbox. Thank you very much tho for your help!

Comment: Where is the ListBox? You may be able to make changes to the ListBox but you may not see it. You are able to make Excel activate a certain sheet on startup but can you see the ListBox even if it shows the ActiveSheet?

Comment: The listbox is on a user form and yes the user form is loaded when the workbook is opened and prevented from closing. Everything regarding the listbox works. It just dosen't automatically highlight the active worksheet when the workbook is loaded and dosen't reflect changes made with the mouse on the workbook itself. Changes made within the listbox reflect and switch worksheet.