# Userform Combo Box Will Not Show All Open Excel Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I'm trying to create a UserForm where all open Excel Workbooks are displayed in the Combo Box, but for some reason, despite having several workbooks clearly open, no results display in the dropdown of the Combo Box.

This is the code of the UserForm

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MyFile = Me.SourceSlate.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Hide
    Stopped = True
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub SourceSlate_UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Me.Label.Caption = "Select the Source slate from the list of open Excel Workbooks below"
    With Me.SourceSlate
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            .AddItem wkb.Name
        Next wkb
    End With
End Sub
```

and this is the code for the module to run the UserForm

```
Option Explicit

Public MyFile As String
Public Stopped As Boolean

Sub SourceSlate_UserForm()

    Stopped = False

    SourceSlate.Show

    If Stopped Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Your Initialize event procedure can't run because it's misnamed. The correct name is `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()`. The underlying logic is that VBA is aware of which userform has caused this event. You may also like to take at look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311132/highlight-listbox-function/60311941?noredirect=1#comment106709882_60311941. Look at the way the form is called.

Comment: I've cleaned up the code a little
```
Option Explicit
 
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Windows(ComboBox1.Value).Activate
    Unload Me
End Sub
 
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    Me.Hide
    Unload Me
End Sub
 
Private Sub SourceSlate_Initialize()
Dim wkb As Workbook
    Me.Label1.Caption = "Select the Source slate from the list of open Excel Workbooks below"
    For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
        If Application.Workbooks(wkb.Name).Visible Then _
            ComboBox1.AddItem wkb.Name
        Next
    
End Sub
```
but, the combo box doesn't display any open workbks

Comment: The Cbx will display nothing until you open the dropdown or set `.Listindex = 0` (to show the first item on the list). Of course, your code adds the items to Me.SourceSlate which seems to be the form. The drop-down should be in the Cbx, perhaps `With ComboBox1`?